# ohmyzsh zsh-autosuggestions forward-word: treat underscore as part of word and not as separator

Tags: macos, zsh

I have been enjoying the zsh-autosuggestions plugin in ohmyzsh on Mac Os Mojave (https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) and I'm using the ctr+space key binding to complete single words, which is often more useful than the usual right-arrow key-press that completes the entire line.

Setting: bindkey "^ " forward-word

Completing single words works better for me, but I noticed that the underscore (_) character is considered as a separator by default, forcing me to use the key combination multiple times in order to complete words containing multiple underscores. How can I tell (ohmy)zsh to consider the underscore char as if it were an alphanumeric one?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `_` to `$WORDCHARS` in your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
WORDCHARS+='_'
```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-WORDCHARS